# T-SQL GROUP BY with Count () and Calculations Not grouping and Counting correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

I wrote code with the purpose of grouping at the "CurrentStatus", counting the number of records by "currentstatus" that are "IN' and "OUT", then dividing the "OUT" records by the total number of records for specific "CurrentStatus" by the Total number records for the "CurrentStatus" ( IN + OUT) to get the Percentage of "OUT" in the "CurrentStatus". Below is a snippet of the code.

```css
SELECT DISTINCT
convert(date, Getdate(), 1) [Date],
channel,
CurrentStatus,
(select count(number) from dbo.vw_AP where channel = 'C' AND [In/Out of Tolerance] = 'in') [In],
(select count(number) from dbo.vw_AP where channel = 'C' AND [In/Out of Tolerance] = 'out') [Out],
count(number) [Total],
convert(Decimal(18,2), (1.0 * (select count(number) from dbo.vw_AgedPipeline where channel = 'C' AND [In/Out of Tolerance] = 'out') / count(number))) [OOTP]
FROM [dbo].[vw_AgedPipeline]
WHERE Channel = 'C'
GROUP BY CurrentStatus, channel 
order by Channel, CurrentStatus
```

The Results this code brings back for "IN" is the total number of "IN' by Channel (instead of CurrentStatus), "OUT" is the total number of "OUT" by channel, and "TOTAL" is the total number by "CurrentStatus". I want the code to group by CurrentStatus for "IN", "OUT", and "TOTAL". Can anyone help?

Comment: Which DBMS? sqlserver <> mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT  
     convert(date, Getdate(), 1) [Date]
    ,v.channel
    ,v.CurrentStatus
    ,count(CASE WHEN  A.[In/Out of Tolerance] = 'in'  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) [In]
    ,count(CASE WHEN  A.[In/Out of Tolerance] = 'out' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) [Out]
    ,count(v.number) [Total]
FROM [dbo].[vw_AgedPipeline] V
INNER JOIN dbo.vw_AP A ON v.Channel = A.Channel
WHERE V.Channel = 'C'
GROUP BY v.channel,v.CurrentStatus
order by v.channel,v.CurrentStatus
)
SELECT [Date]
       ,channel
       ,CurrentStatus
       ,[In]
       ,[Out]
       ,[Total]
       ,convert(Decimal(18,2),  (1.0 * [Out]) / ([Total] * 1.0)) [OOTP]
FROM CTE
```